# While installing nodejs 18.15.0 LTS via curl the file nodesource_setup.sh contents a 404 error

Tags: nodejs

the command is
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.15.0 -o nodesource_setup.sh
look like the setup file is wrong as it says "404" as file content.
Is it something being done wrong my side or nodejs is not allowing to download and write the file?

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; so are you using one of the release where it reports as *working* or *broken*...   As you provided us with no details; how are we to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file that you are trying to download returns a `404 Not Found` error because the file does not exist on the server. The results of `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.15.0` are as follows:

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: right. I tried multiple ways to install node18 to Ubuntu 22 but failed. At last I removed nodejs and did a fresh installation then it workd.